# Unable to reset Root Password: windows, MySQL8.0

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-8.0

I have forgotten my root password and I am following the [official page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/8.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html) to reset my password.I have followed the exact steps.

When I run the `sql-init.txt` file my bash gets stuck and the installation never completes.

```
C:\Windows\system32>cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt --console
2019-03-04T12:06:43.930229Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.
2019-03-04T12:06:43.932934Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 2556
2019-03-04T12:06:48.805422Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-03-04T12:06:48.996196Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.15'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-03-04T12:06:49.078797Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

The commandline was getting stuck. So , I had to close it forcefully(Ctrl+C).
Restarting my computer and MySQL services got it working.
Password was set to the new one.